# Задача про купюры

Tags: delphi, циклы

Всем доброго времени  суток, пишу курсовик, но завис в одной процедуре, никак не могу решить...
Задача такая:

> По нажатию кнопки производится подсчет
> из суммы `rew`, какое количество
> купюр надо выдать из имеющихся
> (`rub5000`, `rub1000`, `rub500`,
> `rub100`, `rub50`, `rub10`). Количество купюр `p` строго
> ограничено, то есть, к примеру, если
> не хватает одной купюры 5000р, то
> программа должна заменить ее на
> эквивалентное количество других купюр.

Вот тут то у меня и возникла проблема.

```
procedure TForm2.Button3Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
    label1.Caption := '5000 = 0 шт.';
    label2.Caption := '1000 = 0 шт.';
    label3.Caption := '500 = 0 шт.';
    label4.Caption := '100 = 0 шт.';
    label5.Caption := '50 = 0 шт.';
    label6.Caption := '10 = 0 шт.';
    while rew > 0 do
    begin
        if rew >= rub5000 then
        begin
            while (rew > rub5000) or (p > 0) do
            begin
                k := rew div rub5000;
                p := ini.ReadInteger('Купюры', '5000', p);
                p := p - k;
                label1.Caption := '5000 руб. = ' + inttostr(k) + ' шт.';
                ini.WriteInteger('Купюры', '5000', p);
                ini.ReadString('Купюры', '5000', label12.Caption);
                rew := rew - (rub5000 * k);
            end;
           p := 1
       end else
       if (rew >= rub1000) and (rew < 5000) then
       begin
           while (rew > rub1000) or (p > 0) do
           begin
               k := rew div rub1000;
               p := ini.ReadInteger('Купюры', '1000', p);
               p := p - k;
               label2.Caption := '1000 руб. = ' + inttostr(k) + ' шт.';
               ini.WriteString('Купюры', '1000', inttostr(p));
               ini.ReadString('Купюры', '1000', label13.Caption);
               rew := rew - (rub1000 * k);
           end;
           p := 1
       end else
       if (rew >= rub500) and (rew < 1000) then
       begin
           while (rew > rub500) or (p > 0) do
           begin
               k := rew div rub500;
               p := strtoint(ini.ReadString('Купюры', '500', inttostr(p)));
               p := p - k;
               label3.Caption := '500 руб. = ' + inttostr(k) + ' шт.';
               ini.WriteString('Купюры', '500', inttostr(p));
               ini.ReadString('Купюры', '500', label14.Caption);
               rew := rew - (rub500 * k);
           end;
           p := 1
       end else
       if (rew >= rub100) and (rew < 500) then
       begin
           while (rew > rub100) or (p > 0) do
           begin
               k := rew div rub100;
               p := ini.ReadInteger('Купюры', '100', p);
               p := p - k;
               label4.Caption := '100 руб. = ' + inttostr(k) + ' шт.';
               ini.WriteString('Купюры', '100', inttostr(p));
               ini.ReadString('Купюры', '100', label15.Caption);
               rew := rew - (rub100 * k);
           end;
           p := 1
       end else
       if (rew >= rub50) and (rew < 100) then
       begin
           while (rew > rub50) or (p > 0) do
           begin
               k := rew div rub50;
               p := strtoint(ini.ReadString('Купюры', '50', inttostr(p)));
               p := p - k;
               label5.Caption := '50 руб. = ' + inttostr(k) + ' шт.';
               ini.WriteString('Купюры', '50', inttostr(p));
               ini.ReadString('Купюры', '50', label16.Caption);
               rew := rew - (rub50 * k);
           end;
           p := 1
           end else
           if (rew >= 10) and (rew < 50) then

           begin
               while (rew > rub10) or (p > 0) do
               begin
                   k := rew div rub10;
                   p := strtoint(ini.ReadString('Купюры', '10', inttostr(p)));
                   p := p - k;
                   label6.Caption := '10 руб. = ' + inttostr(k)  + ' шт.';
                   ini.WriteString('Купюры', '10', inttostr(p));
                   ini.ReadString('Купюры', '10', label17.Caption);
                   rew := rew - (rub10 * k);
               end;
           end;
       end;
       label12.Caption := '5000 = ' + ini.ReadString('Купюры', '5000', '') + ' шт.';
       label13.Caption := '1000 = ' + ini.ReadString('Купюры', '1000', '') + ' шт.';
       label14.Caption := '500 = ' + ini.ReadString('Купюры', '500', '') + ' шт.';
       label15.Caption := '100 = ' + ini.ReadString('Купюры', '100', '') + ' шт.';
       label16.Caption := '50 = ' + ini.ReadString('Купюры', '50', '') + ' шт.';
       label17.Caption := '10 = ' + ini.ReadString('Купюры', '10', '') + ' шт.';
   end;
```

Мне кажется, что ошибка здесь банальная, но никак не могу сообразить, как ее исправить.
Надеюсь на помощь.

Comment: @Владимир Archi Укажите строку на которой выдается ошибка.

Comment: Это может быть любая часть подсчета, если `p := p - k;` меньше нуля,
ошибка то не выдается, а вот программа зависает в цикле. И к тому же все равно пишет, что в остатке будет отрицательное количество купюр (в частности 5000), а мне надо, чтоб было не ниже нуля (ведь если есть 2 купюры по 5 тысяч, не могу же я выдать 15 купюр пятитысячных).

Answer (score 3):

```
int  ruble[] = {10, 10, 43, 3421,   76, 1000}; // кол-во купюр
int  nom[]   = {10, 50, 100, 500, 1000, 5000}; // номиналы

void func ()
{
   long int sum;
   std::cout << "Введите сумму" << std::endl;
   std::cin >> sum;
   for (i = 5; i >= 0; i--)
   {
      int x = sum / nom[i];
      std::cout << "необходимое кол-во купюр номинала " << nom[i] << " руб. - " << x << std::endl;
      std::cout << "в наличии - " << ruble[i] << "купюр такого номинала" << std::endl;
      int vydano = (x > ruble[i]) ? ruble[i] : x; // выдано наименьшее кол-во из имеющегося и посчитанного кол-ва купюр
      std::cout << "будет выдано " << vydano << " купюр" << std::endl;
      sum = sum - vydano * nom[i]; // на следующую итерацию будет переведена невыданная сумма
   }
   if (sum > 0)
      std::cout << "в банкомате не хватает денег для проведения операции" << std::endl;
}
```

Это вроде Си-подобного псевдокода. Может и не скомпилироваться, но, надеюсь, общая идея ясна.

Comment: Надо бы проверить, что ввели сумму кратную минимальному номиналу.

Answer (score 2):

***Добавлено. блин, посмотрел на дату, и понял, что прошло уже два года, а может и больше***

Что на счет ошибок, могу сказать так, на глаз:

1) Непонятно откуда берется p. И как я понял, p - это количество купюр.

```
    if rew >= rub5000 then
    begin
        // например сначала загрузим
        // p := ini.ReadInteger('Купюры', '5000', p);
        while (rew > rub5000) or (p > 0) do
        begin
            k := rew div rub5000;
            p := ini.ReadInteger('Купюры', '5000', p);
            p := p - k;
            // Если k будет больше p, то выдадим больше чем купюр
            // if (k>p) then k:=p;
            // p:=p - k;
            label1.Caption := '5000 руб. = ' + inttostr(k) + ' шт.';
            ini.WriteInteger('Купюры', '5000', p);
            // Не понятно что вы считываете в label12.Caption
            ini.ReadString('Купюры', '5000', label12.Caption);
            rew := rew - (rub5000 * k);
        end;
       p := 1
   end else
```

2) Если не хватило 5000-ых валют, тогда нет вариантов

```
   // думаю можно было просто if (rew >= rub1000) then
   // ну и ниже те же ошибки что и в первом пункте
   if (rew >= rub1000) and (rew < 5000) then
   begin
       while (rew > rub1000) or (p > 0) do
       begin
           k := rew div rub1000;
           p := ini.ReadInteger('Купюры', '1000', p);
           p := p - k;
           label2.Caption := '1000 руб. = ' + inttostr(k) + ' шт.';
           ini.WriteString('Купюры', '1000', inttostr(p));
           ini.ReadString('Купюры', '1000', label13.Caption);
           rew := rew - (rub1000 * k);
       end;
       p := 1
   end else
```

3) Еще заикнусь на счет структуры в целом - вы пишете 6 блоков по сути выполняющих одно и то-же, только с разными числами. Такие вещи надо лучше продумывать, или выносить в функции. В качестве примера можете поизучать Си-подомный вариант в ответе.